# can't assign correct object instance to ForeignKey field

Tags: django, socket.io

I want to save messages sent by users in my Django Socket.IO chat application, and have the following models for this:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    """
    Conversation with two or more participants.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

class Message(models.Model):
    """
    Single chat message.
    """
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation,related_name='message_convo')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='message_sender')
    sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My event handler code includes the following:

```
convo = get_object_or_404(Conversation, id=message["room"])
...
m = Message()
m.conversation = convo,
m.content = message["message"]
m.sender = user
m.save()
```

This fails with a completely nonsensical message:
`ValueError: Cannot assign "(<Conversation: ImmaMode, Century>,)": "Message.conversation" must be a "Conversation" instance.`

Since `convo` is returned by `get_object_or_404` and is *clearly* a `Conversation` instance, what can possibly be causing this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m.conversation = convo,
```

The comma?

Comment: Yes, the mother****ing comma. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Funny how you can completely miss things like this when you focus on something. Thanks. :)